# Ускорить процесс выборки из БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq2sql

Есть два класса: сервер и матч.

```
public class Server
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches {get; set;}
}

public class Match
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public sting Timestamp {get; set;}
    ...
    public virtual Server Server {get; set;}
}
```

Между ними связь One-to-many. Нужно посчитать **среднее количество матчей в день** на каждом сервере.

Сейчас это делаю примерно так (пробовал по-разному):
в классе сервер определил метод

```
public double GetAverageMatchesByDay()
{
    if (Matches.Count == 0) return 0;

    retrun Matches
           .ToList()
           .GroupBy(m => DateTimeOffset.Parse(m.Timestamp).UtcDateTime.Date)
           .Select(g => g.Count())
           .Average();
}
```

Ну и дальше, где нужно:

```
foreach(var server in context.Servers)
{
    var averageMatchesPerDay = server.GetAverageMatchesPerDay();    
}
```

Проблема в том, что при **10 000** серверов и всего лишь по **10** матчей на каждом, это работает уже очень долго, матчей предполагается гораздо больше.

**Как правильно реорганизовать связь, либо способ хранения, либо способ выборки всего этого, чтобы скорость ответа не превышала пару секунд?**

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нафига вы храните timestamp строкой? Вы осознаете, что именно из-за строкового типа вы не можете посчитать нужное значение на сервере?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov С вашим комментарием окончательно это осознал, но не нужно так грубить. Спасибо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov только с таким подходом, когда мне нужен обратный процесс, т.е. преобразовать дату из БД в нужный мне формат, возникает та же самая проблема.